# Post request in Django results in broken pipe

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a post request from a react frontend to a django backend to log a user in, and redirect to a new page. The issue I'm having is that even though the request reaches the server and I can get the data when it comes time for django to redirect, the redirect does not happen and their is an output in the console that says "Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 64989)". I've done some research online about this issue, but I still can't figure out how to fix it. However, everything works fine when I use a an html form element with an action and method type. Below I have shared my code.

**React Frontend**

```
handleSubmit = () => {
      let csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken')
      let endpoint = this.state.isLoggingIn ? LOGIN_ENDPOINT : REGISTER_ENDPOINT;
      axios({
          url: endpoint,
          method: "POST",
          data: {
              username: this.state.username,
              password: this.state.password,
              displayName: this.state.displayName,
          },
          headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrfToken},
          responseType: "json",
      }).then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      });
    }
```

**Django Backend**

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #username = request.POST.get('username') <= I use this and below, to get data sent via a form with an action and method set.
        #password = request.POST.get('password')
        body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
        data = simplejson.loads(body_unicode)
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print user
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('chat_app:chat')
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Check you username or password'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'frontend/chat_app/home.html')
```

**Following works but is not what I want**

With this method I can get the data from the input fields (not shown here)
authenticate the user and redirect them properly. However, I do not want to
use this method because I want to pass back any error messages to the submitFunction() that had been called, or process any other data, in the same page that had made the call.

```
<form method="POST" action={ENDPOINT}>
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
                        value={csrftoken}
                        />
                     ....
```

Comment: I don't know much about react, but typically you get this error if you trigger an Ajax call but before it can return the result, the browser moves to a new page. Are you sure the form doesn't cause a standard submit as well as an Ajax event?

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean by Ajax call b? Like making a second call?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Using the form by itself causes a proper submit, and I am able to redirect which is what I want. I will look to see if i'm not making an ajax call by accident anywhere else. Maybe it happens since I have everything wrapped in a form?

Comment: @DanielRoseman So, I removed the form tags from my component and the Broken pipe is not appearing in the console. However, i'm still back to the issue where the application is not redirecting after logging a user in.

Comment: Surely Ajax is what that axios call is doing?

Comment: I'm using axios to make a call to the backend, but I'm not sure if it is Ajax